# Sort an array that has highest point?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How do I sort array that has highest point from `15.00` key?

I have an array look like this:

```
Array
(

    [9] => Array
        (
            [15.00] => 3.0
            [20.00] => 8.0
            [25.00] => 10.5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [15.00] => 2.0
            [20.00] => 5.0
            [25.00] => 2.5
        )


    [4] => Array
        (
            [15.00] => 6.0
            [25.00] => 4.0
            [30.00] => 6.0
        )
)
```

In order it should be: 4, 9 and 2

Comment: @user622378 - there are lots of multidimensional sort functions in the comments of this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), a function enabling you to sort via a user-provided comparison function. There's also [`uasort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) that maintains index association.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$array = Array(
  9 => Array(
            15.00 => 3.0,
            20.00 => 8.0,
            25.00 => 10.5
  ),
  2 => Array(
            15.00 => 2.0,
            20.00 => 5.0,
            25.00 => 2.5
  ),
  4 => Array(
            15.00 => 6.0,
            25.00 => 4.0,
            30.00 => 6.0
  )
);

function my_func($a, $b) {
   if ($a[15.00] == $b[15.00])
      return 0;
   return ($a[15.00] < $b[15.00]) ? 1 : -1; // backwards sorting
}

uasort($array, my_func);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

And [here's it working](http://codepad.org/DQ6viXBQ).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I would personally probably use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). In my callback I would compare `$a[15.00]` and `$b[15.00]`.

Answer (score 2):

You want uasort():

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a[15.00] < $b[15.00]) return 1;
  if ($a[15.00] > $b[15.00]) return -1;
  return 0;
}

uasort($data, "cmp");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?
for ($i=1;$i<=count($arr);$i++)
for ($j=$i+1;$j<=count($arr) - 1;$j++)
 if ($arr[$i]['15.00'] > $arr[$j]['15.00']) {
   $tmp = $arr[$i];
   $arr[$i] = $arr[$j];
   $arr[$j] = $tmp
 }
?>
```